# derivative of $\arcsin \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$

Tags: calculus

**Question**

Please help me find the derivative of $\arcsin \dfrac{(e^{2x}-1)}{(e^{2x}+1)}$

**Answer**

Using the chain rule this can be written as:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1- \left( \dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)^2}} \times \dfrac{2e^{2x}(e^{2x}-1)-2e^{2x}(e^{2x}+1)}{(e^{2x} + 1)^2}$$

This can be simplified to:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1- \left( \dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)^2}} \times \dfrac{-4e^{2x}}{(e^{2x} + 1)^2}$$

The correct answer should be

$$\dfrac{2e^{x}}{e^{2x}+1}$$

I can't really see how they get there...

Comment: Along with the below answers, your quotient rule is backwards, derivative of the numerator comes first, this just makes your expression positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your computations in blocks; first consider
$$
1-\left(\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)^2=
\frac{(e^{2x}+1)^2-(e^{2x}-1)^2}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}=
\frac{4e^{2x}}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)^2}}=
\frac{e^{2x}+1}{2e^x}
$$
Now the derivative of the fraction
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)'
&=
\frac{(e^{2x}-1)'\cdot(e^{2x}+1)-(e^{2x}-1)\cdot(e^{2x}+1)'}
{(e^{2x}+1)^2}
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{2e^{2x}(e^{2x}+1)-2e^{2x}(e^{2x}-1)}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{4e^{2x}}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}
\end{align}

---

There is a slicker way: by definition,
$$
\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=
\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}=
\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\tanh x
$$
and the derivative of $\tanh x$ is
$$
\frac{1}{\cosh^2x}=1-\tanh^2x
$$
so your derivative is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\tanh^2x}}(1-\tanh^2x)=\sqrt{1-\tanh^2x}
=
\frac{1}{\cosh x}=\frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiarized with hyperbolic functions? Note that $$\frac{e^{2 x}-1}{e^{2 x}+1}=\tanh (x)$$

We know that for the circular function $$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \tan(x) = [\sec(x)]^2.$$
I won't go into details, but circular relations hold in the hyperbolic case.

So we have:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arcsin\left(\tanh(x) \right)
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arcsin\left(x \right)\big|_{x=\tanh(x)} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \tanh\left(x \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{[\tanh(x)]^2+1}} \times [\mathrm{sech(x)}]^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{[\mathrm{sech(x)}]^2}} \times [\mathrm{sech(x)}]^2 \\
&= \sqrt{[\mathrm{sech(x)}]^2} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{4}{\left(e^{x}+e^{-x}\right)^2}} \text{, assuming } x \in \mathbb{R},\\
&= \frac{2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{(e^{2x}+1)^2-(e^{2x}-1)^2}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4e^{2x}}{(e^{2x}+1)^2}}=\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}$$

Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

Could it probably help working with hyperbolic functions?

$$\tanh x=\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\frac{\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2}{\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2}=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\implies$$

$$\left(\arcsin\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\right)'=\left(\arcsin\tanh x\right)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\tanh^2x}}\cdot\text{sech}^2x=\frac1{\cosh x}=\text{sech}\,x$$

I think you can leave it that way or instead also write

$$\text{sech}\,x=\frac1{\cosh x}=\frac2{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}$$